# Comparing of melting point of dibromo p-xylenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, halides, melting-point

> [image]

How to compare the melting points of the above isomers? I know that melting point depends upon the packing of the molecule, more efficient the packing, higher is the melting point. Symmetry in a compound also increases it's melting point. But all the above compounds have symmetry in them and I can't figure out how to compare their melting points.

Comment: I and III have 2 planes and 1 axis. II has 1 plane and 1 axis

Comment: @Maurice So what should we conclude from that?

Comment: Based on «the better (i.e., more regular) packing, the higher the melting point»,  my _speculation_ the melting points increase along III -> I -> II.  This extrapolates*) from the packing of atoms in metals.  While none of the three molecular structures is a sphere, in my perception, compound II is the most _sphere like_ of the three.  And neither one of the three has strong hydrogen bond donors and acceptors to increase the strength of the intermolecular attractive interactions (except H-B). *) Of course, extrapolations always come with the danger to potentially lead to a wrong conclusion.

Comment: @Buttonwood: Thank you for your comment. But how are you perceiving the 2nd compound as more sphere like? Can the melting point data be checked from somewhere?

Comment: @Buttonwood I think you should read about [pi-stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-Stacking_(chemistry))

Comment: I am thinking of an answer as for at *a first glance* this series has everything to conjure against rules of thumb. It would be nice if someone has access to the mp of compound I.

Comment: @Mithoron I join Alchimista's comment, «everything [can be used] to conjure against rules of thumb», and substitute _sphere like_ by _more round_.  I can't quantify this.  But the polymorph of II accessible in the [COD](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/2018032.html) (preview [CCSD](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/search?pid=ccdc:824043&sid=IUCr)) looks _more_ herring bone, than $\pi$-stacking, don't you think, too?

Comment: @LightYagami _If prepared_ as compound, and if characterized by recording a melting point, this property would enter the primary literature (e.g., the article), then a database like Scifinder or Reaxys (both commercial).

Comment: @Buttonwood Looks like T-shaped stacking.

Comment: @Buttonwood yes more global symmetric or round... But we are all on the same meaning. Also do not debate about parallel vs herring bone arrangement much. The latter is normally the case with aromatic molecules this size. It is still of stacking led by a pi system and still flat regular symmetric molecule favour that. I really need the mp of I otherwise I would write something more "didactic" than an answer somehow on point... A true one does not exist, or better, one can't do it.

Comment: @Mithoron I couldn't tag you in the above comment.